# Pandas list unpacking to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, chaining, iterable-unpacking

I have a pandas DataFrame with one column containing lists, like:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6], [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df
   A                B
0  1  [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
1  2  [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
2  3  [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
```

I can unpack these lists to individual columns

```
>>> df[['x','y','z']] = df.B.tolist()
>>> df
   A                B    x    y    z
0  1  [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]  0.1  0.2  0.3
1  2  [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]  0.4  0.5  0.6
2  3  [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]  0.7  0.8  0.9
```

but would like to do this with a chaining compatible command.

I thought about using `.assign` but here I need to define each variable explicitly and unpacking via lambdas gets a bit involved.

```
>>> (df.assign(q=lambda df_: df_.B.apply(lambda x: x[0]),
...            w=lambda df_: df_.B.apply(lambda x: x[1]),
...            u=lambda df_: df_.B.apply(lambda x: x[2])))
   A                B    q    w    u
0  1  [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]  0.1  0.2  0.3
1  2  [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]  0.4  0.5  0.6
2  3  [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]  0.7  0.8  0.9
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Btw, you can slice a list without `apply` using `.assign(q=lambda d: d['B'].str[0])` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) is always useful to chain anything:

```
(pd.DataFrame(d)
   .pipe(lambda d: d.join(pd.DataFrame(d['B'].to_list(),
                                       columns=['q', 'w', 'u'],
                                       index=d.index))
        )
)
```

Variant with `pipe`+[`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df.pipe(lambda d: d.assign(**dict(zip(['q', 'w', 'u'], zip(*d['B'].to_list())))))
```

Output:

```
   A                B    q    w    u
0  1  [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]  0.1  0.2  0.3
1  2  [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]  0.4  0.5  0.6
2  3  [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]  0.7  0.8  0.9
```

Comment: Great idea to do it via `pipe`, many thanks @mozway! The `pipe`+`assign` variant is maybe a bit hacky for production code, but your idea for the in-place creation of a dict is really cool.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the great hints from @mozway, with two simplifications:

Use `zip` to create a `dict` inside of `assign`:

```
df.assign(**dict(zip(['x', 'y', 'z'], zip(*df['B']))))
```